# How can I upgrade from rails 6.1.4 to rails 7 and remove webpacker the previous version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I installed rails version 6.1.4 but now I'd like to go to version 7.0.0 and remove the webpacker that was installed by default in its entirety

If you could help me I'd be grateful